# I want to do the same, but with a .csv file. Its possible?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, charts, pastebin

I am new on stack overflow and with R

I want to monitorize the hours of sleep, so I found very nice this project. 
I thought that I would write the data in a .csv. Some like this:

```r
Date ,hms1,hms2
2005-01-01,00:00:00,09:17:00
2005-01-02,00:12:00,10:02:00
2005-01-03,00:15:00,08:02:00
2005-01-04,01:32:00,07:04:00
2005-01-05,02:34:00,05:04:00
2005-01-06,03:34:00,05:05:00
2005-01-07,01:02:00,04:04:00
2005-01-08,00:12:00,04:04:00
2005-01-09,04:32:00,09:04:00
2005-01-10,06:33:00,10:02:00
2005-01-11,01:02:00,08:05:00
2005-01-12,22:30:00,03:03:00
2005-01-13,02:00:00,05:55:00
```

I don't know how to read the data from the .csv in R. I have tried with this code:

```r
Data <- read.csv("hora2.csv", sep = ";", Headers = TRUE, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

but that didn´t work.

The code which I am working is this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(stringr)

#hms Hora Minutos Segundos
df1$Date = as.POSIXct(df1$Date) + 3600*8
set.seed(20)

df1$hms1a = df1$Date + runif(nrow(df1), 3600*5, 3600*10)
df1$hms2a = df1$Date + runif(nrow(df1), 3600*15, 3600*66)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date)) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 day")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,48), breaks=seq(0,48,2),
                     labels=str_pad(seq(0,48,2) %% 24, 2, pad="0")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=seq(0,48,24)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = hms1a - Date, ymax = hms2a - Date), color = "#63C1FF",size = 5) +
  coord_flip() + ylab("Tiempo en horas") +
  ggtitle("Horas de Sueño")
```

Comment: i am not able to post the links and the photo. Sorry, I am new here

Comment: If the issue is just reading the csv file tell us how it didn't work and I suggest the second section of code is irrelevant and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are separated by `,` you should use `,` as separator. Therefore try

```r
Data <- read.csv("hora2.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

instead of

```r
Data <- read.csv("hora2.csv", sep = ";", Headers = TRUE, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I have tried too. The console give me this error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :   "hms1 object not found"

Comment: Please be precise: What did you do and when did the error occured?

Comment: I think that the sintaxy its wrong at some point for read the .csv https://i.imgur.com/82G9qCL.jpg *Object not found its the error

Comment: Thank you so much! I have realized that the slasher "/" of the directory in the read quote was wrong. Right now the interpreter can read the .cvs! great. Now I found a new error. The time columns be "not-numeric for a binary operator" How can fix that? https://i.imgur.com/aNsdEt6.jpg

Comment: Please ask a new question, if you found a new error. A question has to be about one specific problem. Any new problem, that occurs should result in a whole new question.

Comment: @Raul If you are going to ask a new question, please make sure to include some sample data. And please don't use images, since there are several ways to post code and error messages.

Comment: @Raul And feel free to accept the answer, if it helped you. :-)